# Target shape failing on LSTM Keras classifier

Tags: numpy, keras, lstm, reshape

I want to fit the `value` assigned to each time step determined by the `walk` sequence.

I am not able to find how to shape `y_onehot` properly. At the moment I am getting the following error:

```
---> 64 model.fit(X, y_onehot.reshape(3, 12), epochs=100, batch_size=1, verbose=2)

   ValueError: Shapes (1, 12) and (1, 3) are incompatible
```

This is the code I am using:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, Masking
from keras.utils import np_utils, pad_sequences


# read in data
df = pd.DataFrame({
                   'value': ['A',  'A',  'A',  'C',  'C',   'C', 'C',  'C',  'B', 'B', 'B',  'B'],
                   'X1':    [1.2,  1.5,  0.91, 3.5,  0.2,   2.7, 2.2,  0.91, 3.5, 0.2, 0.91, 2.4],
                   'X2':    [2.4,  0.82, 2.1,  0.4,  4.4,   3.5, 0.2,  2.7,  2.2, 4.2, 3.4,  0.9],
                   'walk': ['d', 'd',   'd',  'sa', 'sa', 'sa', 'sa', 'sa', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p'], 
                   'time':  [1,    2,    3,    1,    2,     3,   4,    5,     1,   2,   3,    4]})

# set parameters
TIME_STEPS = max(df.groupby(['walk'])['time'].count())
NUM_FEATURES = 2  # the number of X features

# encode the output variable
y = df['value'].values
encoder = LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit(y)
encoded_y = encoder.transform(y)
y_onehot = np_utils.to_categorical(encoded_y)

# Another alternative: convert the output sequences to one-hot encoding
classes = df['value'].unique()
class_to_int = dict(zip(classes, range(len(classes))))
int_to_class = dict(zip(range(len(classes)), classes))
y = [[class_to_int[val] for val in y_wals] for y_wals in y]
y = pad_sequences(y, maxlen=max_length, dtype='float32', padding='post', value=-1)
y = np.asarray([[[1 if val == i else 0 for i in range(len(classes))] for val in y_walk] for y_walk in y])


# split the data into input and output sequences
X = []
y = []
for walk, group in df.groupby('walk'):
    x_walk = group[['X1', 'X2']].values
    y_walk = group['value'].values
    X.append(x_walk)
    y.append(y_walk)


# pad the input sequences with zeros to the maximum length
X = pad_sequences(X, maxlen=TIME_STEPS, dtype='float32', padding='post', value=0.0)

# create a binary mask for the padded elements
mask = np.zeros(X.shape, dtype='float32')
for i, row in enumerate(X):
    mask[i, :len(row)] = 1.0


# define the LSTM model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Masking(mask_value=0.0, input_shape=(max_length, 2)))
model.add(LSTM(units=50, input_shape=(max_length, 2)))
model.add(Dense(len(classes), activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())

# fit the model
model.fit(X, y_onehot.reshape(3, 12), epochs=100, batch_size=1, verbose=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, Masking
from keras.utils import np_utils, pad_sequences


# read in data
df = pd.DataFrame({
                   'value': ['A',  'A',  'A',  'C',  'C',   'C', 'C',  'C',  'B', 'B', 'B',  'B'],
                   'X1':    [1.2,  1.5,  0.91, 3.5,  0.2,   2.7, 2.2,  0.91, 3.5, 0.2, 0.91, 2.4],
                   'X2':    [2.4,  0.82, 2.1,  0.4,  4.4,   3.5, 0.2,  2.7,  2.2, 4.2, 3.4,  0.9],
                   'walk': ['d', 'd',   'd',  'sa', 'sa', 'sa', 'sa', 'sa', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p'], 
                   'time':  [1,    2,    3,    1,    2,     3,   4,    5,     1,   2,   3,    4]})

# set parameters
TIME_STEPS = max(df.groupby(['walk'])['time'].count())
NUM_FEATURES = 2  # the number of X features
max_length = TIME_STEPS

classes = df['value'].unique()


# split the data into input and output sequences
X = []
y = []
for walk, group in df.groupby('walk'):
    x_walk = group[['X1', 'X2']].values
    y_walk = group['value'].values
    X.append(x_walk)
    y.append(y_walk[0])

encoder = LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit(y)
encoded_y = encoder.transform(y)
y_onehot = np_utils.to_categorical(encoded_y)

# pad the input sequences with zeros to the maximum length
X = pad_sequences(X, maxlen=TIME_STEPS, dtype='float32', padding='post', value=0.0)

# create a binary mask for the padded elements
mask = np.zeros(X.shape, dtype='float32')
for i, row in enumerate(X):
    mask[i, :len(row)] = 1.0


# define the LSTM model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Masking(mask_value=0.0, input_shape=(max_length, 2)))
model.add(LSTM(units=50, input_shape=(max_length, 2)))
model.add(Dense(len(classes), activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())

# fit the model
model.fit(X, y_onehot, epochs=1, batch_size=1, verbose=2)


model.predict(np.array([X[0]]))
```